# Force start Rails application through foreman only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreman

I am using foreman in my Rails application and all works fine when I run `foreman start` but sometime I forget it and run only Rails application as `rails s`. Then I spend some time trying to investigate problems related to not working services (like sidekiq).

So, can somebody recommend a way how to force starting my application through foreman only? In other cases I want to see error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an environment variable to `.env`, which is read when Foreman starts, and then check for its presence  in a Rails initializer.